# Postgresql: Unique constraint over Union of 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

TRANSACTIONS

```
 id   |   amount
------------------
  1   |    100
  2   |    -100
  3   |    250
  4   |   -250
```

TRANSACTION_LINKS

```
id  | send_tx  | receive_tx
---------------------------
 1  |     2    |     1 
 2  |     4    |     2
```

The `send_tx` and `receive_tx` columns in the transaction links table use foreign keys pointing to the ID of the transactions table.

This is how I create the transaction links table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transaction_links
(
    id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    send_id       INT NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES transactions(id) ON DELETE
    RESTRICT,
    receive_id    INT NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES transactions(id) ON DELETE
    RESTRICT
);
```

I want to create a unique constraint over both `send_tx` and `receive_tx`, meaning that if transaction id 1 is found in the `receive_tx column`, then

- no other transaction link can have the `receiving_tx` =  1
- no other transaction link can have the `sending_tx` = 1

I know that I can have a unique constraint on each column separately, but that only solves my first problem

**EDIT:**

essentially, if I insert (1,2) into transaction links, then inserting (1,3) or (3,1) or (4,2) or (2,4) should all be rejected
Also, in my design, the transactions table contains many more columns than what is shown here, I've only included the amount for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Are you sure you're modelling this right? I'd normally be thinking that a single transaction row would identify a sender, a receiver and an amount (the amount to be debited from the sender and credited to the receiver). Splitting the send and receive parts into separate rows seems odd. Further splitting the linking together of these facts into another table does too. Because surely the next question becomes how you enforce that the amounts in the two transaction rows "match up" with each other...

Comment: in reality, my transactions table has multiple columns asides from the id and amount shown in my example, which means that i cannot group everything into one table

Comment: Still, your current model is "surprising". I can pair two transactions that both represent credits, or that are for imbalanced amounts. Unless you're using unusual terminology, a financial transaction is a transfer of an amount *from* one place and *to* another and that should be modelled as a single fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) which only requires a single index:

```
alter table transaction_links
  add constraint check_tx
  exclude using gist ( (array[send_id, receive_id]) with &&);
```

The `&&` operator is the "overlaps" operator for arrays - which means "have elements in common, regardless of the order of the elements in the array. In this case the constraint prevents to insert any row where any value of `(send_id, receive_id)` appears in some other row of the table (regardless of the column).

However, you need the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) extension for that.

Online example: https://rextester.com/QOYS23482

Comment: is there no other way this can be done without gist? id like to avoid installing additional modules if possible

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name each time i try to use gist i get an error: 
 data type integer[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Comment: @EllaLautier: ah, right. Sorry. That needs the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) extension - but installing it is as simple as `create extension intarray;`