# UNIQUE constraint across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint

I need a `UNIQUE` constraint which spans 2 columns, but allows NULL values anywhere. I have this :

```
CREATE TABLE table_1{
  COLUMN a INT SET DEFAULT NULL,
  COLUMN b INT SET DEFAULT NULL
 -- <insert constraint here>
}
```

Some examples:

```
a  b
1  2
3  4
valid
```

```
a  b
1  1
2  3
invalid
```

```
a  b
1  2
1  3
invalid
```

```
a  b
1  2
3  1
invalid
```

```
a  b
1  2
3  NULL
valid
```

```
a  b
1  2
3  NULL
4 NULL
NULL 5
valid
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to prevent any single value from appearing more than once in either `a` or `b` columns in all rows?

Comment: @Dai Exactly that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687727/postgresql-unique-constraint-over-union-of-2-columns/54687893#54687893

Answer (score 2):

modification of @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion

```sql
create table table_1(a int default null, b int default null);
ALTER TABLE table_1
    ADD CONSTRAINT excl exclude using gist ( (array_remove(array[a, b],NULL)) with &&);
```

this will work fine with NULLable columns